# setContentView() not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Here's my code:

```
    
    public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {          
        private Button mHorizontalButton;
        private Button mVerticalButton;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            mHorizontalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_button);
            mVerticalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vertical_button);
            mHorizontalButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            mVerticalButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.horizontal_button:
                    setContentView(R.layout.horizontal);
                    break;
                case R.id.vertical_button:
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                    break;      
            }
        }
    }
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This layout is vertical." />
    <Button
        android:text="Click for a horizontal layout"
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**horizontal.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This layout is horizontal." />
    <Button
        android:text="Click for a vertical layout"
        android:id="@+id/vertical_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It is supposed, that by clicking on button I'll get the horizontal view, and then after clicking once again - vertical.

But after clicking nothing happens. What might be the issue?

Comment: How are you doing now? Why not follow my answer?

Comment: It seemed to me too complicated. Then I noticed someone left negative feedback (-1), though it was not efficient, sorry.

Comment: Ok, I just want to point that: if you just call `setContentView()` to show different layout, then every time when you show a new view, you have to bind the listener again.You have to call `button.setOnclickListener(this);` again after set a new view. The most effecient way to bind the listener is to set the `onClick` attribute in the layout file. Also, I tested, you can use `v==button` to determine which button is clicked.

Comment: @Huang, that was valuable advice, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must either call setOnClickListener, as suggested by others or
set the onclick XML attribute in your layout.

Like this:

```
 <Button
                android:onClick="buttonClick"
                android:id="+@id/button1"
                android:text="@string/button" />
```

in your code:

```
public void buttonClick(View button)
{
   if (button.getId() == R.id.button1)
   { // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Do not mind but I think you are not new to svf.If some one has give same answer then its better to appreciate his answer rather than posting new answer

Comment: With 3k reputation I'm not new, and my answer in not the same but points out a different approach.

Comment: @Drejc, this helped me :) Thanks. This was easier and better, than suggested Sameer.

Comment: @Drejc, I have 13 reputation, can't upvote it, must have 15 instead.

Answer (score 2):

compare like this v.getId() == R.id.mHorizontalButton.as we can not compare view using ==.
Next correction is set onclickListener to button

mVerticalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vertical_button);

mVerticalButton.setOnclickListener(this).

Now it will work.

Comment: I've edited my post, look at the code again, it still doesn't work. I get an "Sorry! The application....Force close." error.

Comment: what error show in your logcat.?try to debug your application.put the code in try catch block.when you will debug line by line you will easily find problem

Comment: mVerticalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vertical_button);
  mVerticalButton.setOnClickListener(this); this button id vertical_button not present in main xml.So comment this line then run

Comment: I get a 
02-18 14:49:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(385): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{on.my.way/on.my.way.Business}: java.lang.NullPointerException

After commenting 2 button lines the program runs.
Where do I have nullpointer here?

Comment: read my previous comment ..i have already address your issue.mVerticalButton is null as its not part of main.xml.remove these two line

Comment: Ok, now I got it.I got the layout, which should be after pressing the button, but after that I can't get the previous, with clicking the new appeared button, because I commented that line. So how can I solve this now?

Comment: first read what is the layout,button etc.then came here.As its not possible to tell each and every step here.stack overflow is just to give instruction if stuck

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if (v == mHorizontalButton)` and `else if (v == mVerticalButton)`, you must use:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
 case R.id.horizontal_button:
// your processing
break;
case R.id.vertical_button:
  // your processing
break;
```

Comment: what will happen if he does not use switch case?Is this will not click?

Comment: no, it is will click. but usually i use switch case instead of if else

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    if (v.getId() == R.id.horizontal_button) 
    {
         Log.i(message, "i'm here");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    } 
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.vertical_button) 
    {
        Log.i(message, "i'm here");
        setContentView(R.layout.horizontal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working solution:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {          
    private Button mHorizontalButton;
    private Button mVerticalButton;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mHorizontalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_button);
        mVerticalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vertical_button);
    }

    public void buttonClick(View button) {
       if (button.getId() == R.id.vertical_button) { 
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
       } else if(button.getId() == R.id.horizontal_button) {
            setContentView(R.layout.horizontal);           
       }
    }
}
```

And in `xml`:

```
 <Button
      android:onClick="buttonClick"
      android:id="@+id/vertical_button" <!-- for another button: @+id/horizontal_button -->
      />
```